# the_content в вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

во время работы с вордпресс у меня возник вопрос. Когда я перехожу на другую страницу, я могу отобразить контент из админки функцией the_content, но предположим мне нужно отобразить гугл карту, как это сделать без плагинов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> но предположим мне нужно отобразить гугл карту, как это сделать без
>   плагинов?

Без плагинов - например вставить код гуглокарты в созданный кастомный шаблон и выбрать его для нужной записи.

См https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Но с плагинами и проще и удобнее и в целом правильнее.

Comment: А если мне нужно вставить код php, какой плагин мне лучше всего использовать?

Comment: @Asen123 это другой вопрос. Задай его отдельно и укажи куда именно вставить и для чего - чтобы показать или что бы он выполнился.